# How to untargz files using maven?

Tags: maven, tar, gzip

Using maven, I download some Chef cookbooks.

Received files are in the `.tgz` format, and I want to unpack them. How can I do that ? Is there any useful plugin ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [what](http://www.ehow.com/how_5021436_unzip-tgz-files.html) I know, .tgz can be unpack via two commands:

```
   gzip -d file.tgz
   tar xvf file.tar
```

So you can use [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html) to execute these two tasks:

```
   <gunzip src="tools.tgz"/>
   <untar src="tools.tar" dest="${tools.home}"/>
```

Ant task reference: [gunzip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/gunzip.html) and [untar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/untar.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [truezip-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/) to handle such archives.